# Call center Implementa​tion in Visual force page

Tags: visualforce

I have a small requirement ,

Actually My client using Avaya Call center Application in Salesorce (like a soft phone),

With this Call center Agents are getting the calls from the customers through the call center Application,

After ending the call they entering the Comments about the Call, and they are selecting one Wrap up code(among 27 wrapup codes, these wrap up codes are nothing but the issues that the Customer had).

And then they are clicking on Done button (Which is in Call center Itself).

When they are 'Done ' the Call log (Call Information) is Saved in Active history of Related Account (as one record),

In that Call log The Call result is Wrap up code Value, And Comment is entered Text(Agent entered Comment).

Requirement,

Our the Actual requirement is

Now the Agent will able to Save one call log.

But If the Customer on the call had multiple issues.

For this I need to design a custom page which can call the Call center data during the Call,

Can we integrate the call center Data in to our visual force page during the Call is it possible,

In my custom page:

My custom Page contains some check boxes these are nothing but the wrapup codes in the call center, and when Agent Checks the checkbox a textbox need to be appear below the check box where they can enter Comments

With this the Agent able to enter Multiple issues by checking the Check boxes and entering multiple comments on each issue in that text areas.

But I don't know whether we can call the Subject field and related to field and Call duration (All Call information) from the Call center to our visual force Page

Can anybody please suggest me...

How to do this .....

Comment: The way you have submitted your question, is not going to attract any answers I fear. I suggest you try and divide your question into more granular ones, where it will invite more users to answer and participate.